# importing access 2003 database to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am importing an MS Access 2003 database to SQL Server 2008 through the SQL server import and export wizard. The database is imported successfully, but when I look at the tables on both sides, they are different. For example, some of the tables that are there in the access database are not present in SQL Server while some created in SQL Server are not present in the original database.

[image]

Some of the tables absent from the original database are highlighted
[image]

Why is this happening? How can I verify the import then?

**Important edit:** It is importing the queries instead of tables. The entries seen in the wizard are present as queries in the original database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of the 2003 Upsize Wizard. I suggest you create a new SQL database and then import the tables and data using SSMS by right clicking the Database node and select Tasks then Import Data... Then make sure you have a Primary Key established for each table in SQL Server, then create ODBC linked tables in your front end mdb.

Comment: I'm not using the Upsize Wizard. I was importing the data through SQL Server Import and Export Wizard which is exactly the same as in the steps you described and produces identical results.